# Finding prime number in javascript

Tags: javascript

There are several ways of checking if a given number is prime or not. I want to find it in by own way and if the given number is not prime, I am trying to find next higher prime number.
so far I tried the following and can't understand why it's creating infinite loop. Could you please correct my code. Or tell me what wrong I am doing here.

```
function myFunction(a){
 for(i=2; i<=a; i++){
  if(a % i != 0){
  console.log(" Prime ")
  }
   else{
     a++  // creates infinite loop
     if(a % i == 0){
     console.log("not prime")
     } 
     else{
      console.log("prime")
     }   
   }
}
 console.log(a)
}

myFunction(38) // Expected 41
```

Comment: 7 is a prime ... so why would the expected return be 11?

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII sorry, mistake

Comment: to prove a number x is not a prime ... you have to show, that x % y !== 0 (for y beeing the interval [2, x/2) (2 inclusive, x/2 exclusive) - you are only checking one y out of many - you have to make sure, that you check x against all number in the interval (not only one) - only after that you can say x is not a prime

Comment: To be clear, this questioner isn't asking how to find primes, they are self-teaching and want to work that out themselves.  The questioner is asking why the loop isn't terminating.  The loop isn't terminating because the condition `i>a` is never reached.  Why not? Because for non-prime `a`'s greater than 2, the loop increments `a` along with incrementing `i`.  The `i` variable is forever chasing an ever increasing `a`, never catching up so `i<=a` remains true forever.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII this is much clear to me now. Thank you.

Comment: @danh yes much clear now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are mistakes in your code?

1. what is Prime? prime is a number that divided by all the numbers from 2 to itself - 1, and it is not divided by 1 or itself. so exclude `a` in for loop, otherwise all numbers are not prime in opinion of your function: `for (i = 2; i <= a - 1; i++)`
2. Prime numbers follow Counterexample, mean all numbers are prime unless it can divided by a number:

```
function myFunction(a) {
        for (i = 2; i <= a - 1; i++) {
            if (a % i == 0) {
                console.log("Not Prime");
                return;
            }
        }
        console.log("Prime");
        return;
    }
```

3.you have a `for` loop and many times it need a `break` or `return` statement, for example in there. using `if` you find that the number is not prime, so `break` or `return` (if you want to do something for example find next prime, do that and `break` or `return`)

4. at the end of `loop` and when you find there is no number that can divide `a` so `log` this is prime and `retuen`
5. do something like that for finding next prime:

```
function myFunction(a) {
        for (i = 2; i <= a - 1; i++) {
            if (a % i == 0) {
                console.log("Not Prime");
                while(true) {
                    a++;
                    let isPrime = true;
                    for (i = 2; i <= a - 1; i++) {
                        if (a % i == 0) {
                            isPrime = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isPrime){
                        console.log(a);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("Prime");
    }

    myFunction(38)
```

6. `isPrime` is a flag that find that if the number is prime or not, if it is `true` so `log` and `return`

at last, a better way:

```
function isPrime(number) {
    if (number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function myFunction(number) { 
    if (isPrime(number)) {
        return "Prime";
    } else {
        while (true) {
            number++;
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                return number;
            }
        }
    }
 }
console.log(myFunction(39));
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, It's very clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

You had several wrong things. If you want a solution see below. If you want hints, I can give you:

1. two loops or two functions
2. don't increment the `a` in the for loop when you are going from `i` to `a`
3. when `x % y == 0` then `x` is not a prime.
4. you can't stop the loop when `x % y != 0` because you haven't proved it is prime yet.

Spoiler:

```js
// code re-use right here
const isPrime = num => {
  for (let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++)
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}

function closestPrime(num) {
  while (!isPrime(num)) {
    num++
  }
  return num;
}
console.log(closestPrime(38))
console.log(closestPrime(7))
```

Comment: no offense but your code is available over internet, I trying to understand what I am doing wrong in my code. I am newbie and trying to understand how for loop and increments works in programming language.

Comment: Sure no problem. I gave you a few pointers and if you need something specific just ask.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function nextPrime(integer){
  //Store primes and initiate index
  let primes = [2]
  let index = 3
  //while the last prime found is less that the parameter
  while(primes[primes.length -1] <= integer){
    //if index is not divisible by any prime
    if(primes.every(elem => index%elem != 0)){
        //add to primes
        primes.push(index)
    } 
    index ++
  }
  //return last prime found (greater than parameter)
  return primes[primes.length -1]
}
console.log(nextPrime(38))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  flag = true
  if(num<2) {
    flag=false;
  }
  for (let  j = 2; j <= Math.ceil(num/2); j++) {
      if(num%j==0) {
          flag = false
          break
      }
    }
  return flag
}
console.log(isPrime(2))      //type number for check
```

This function checks whether a given number is a prime number and returns the result as true or false.

The function takes a parameter named num, and it initially sets a variable named flag to true. The flag variable will be used to hold the result.

If the value of num is less than 2 (negative, 0, or 1), the flag variable is updated to false, as numbers less than 2 are not prime positive integers.

The function uses a loop with a variable j starting from 2 and going up to Math.ceil(num/2). This range is sufficient to check whether the number num can be evenly divided by values between 2 and itself.

If the remainder of dividing num by j is 0, it means num is not a prime number, and the flag variable is updated to false.

If the loop completes, and the flag variable remains true, it indicates that num is a prime number.

Finally, the function returns the last value of the flag variable, which will be either true or false. Thus, the function will return true if the number is prime and false if it is not.

For example, isPrime(2) will return true because 2 is a prime number. However, isPrime(10) will return false because 10 is not a prime number.